# Funky Debugging, what is happening here?

Tags: c++, compilation, visual-studio-2013

With this project I am experiencing something I can't crasp at all. The projects are compiling, and seems to work perfect.

While debugging the execution line jumps all over the scope.

After entering the scope at line 3 the following sequence occurs
    - 5, 8, 10, **8**, **10**, 9, **10**, 11, 13

This can't be correct, what is happening?

**Debug snippet:**

```
 1 void
 2 cLogger::Log(std::string text)
 3 {
 4 
 5     if (LogWrite)
 6     {
 7 
 8         LogMessage  msg;
 9         msg.type = Logger::None;
10         msg.message = text;
11         LogWrite(msg);
12 
13     }
14 
15 }
```

LogWrite is: typedef std::function< void(LogMessage&) > OnLogWrite;

LogMessage is a simple struct with a std::string and an enumerator;

cLogger is a descent from a singleton, which is an Ogre::Singleton but placed (for now) in my own lib (realm.shared.lib).

**Output log:**

```
1>------Rebuild All started : Project : realm.shared, Configuration : Debug Win32------
1>  Singleton.cpp
1>  realm.shared.vcxproj->D:\Development\Projects\Realm\bin\Debug\realm.shared.lib
2>------Rebuild All started : Project : Realm.Server.Application, Configuration : Release Win32------
2>  cApplication.cpp
2>  cCommand.cpp
2>  cConsole.cpp
2>  main.cpp
2>  cLogger.cpp
2>  cServer.cpp
2>  Generating code
2>  Finished generating code
2>  Realm.Server.Application.vcxproj->D:\Development\Projects\Realm\bin\Release\Realm.Server.Application.exe
== == == == == Rebuild All : 2 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped == == == == ==
```

*(don't know for sure if the tag VS2013 is in place here)*

*(if more information is needed, or less, place tell: really don't know what is happening here)*

Comment: Why is `Realm.Server.Application` and thus `cLogger.cpp` built in Release configuration?

Comment: Change it into Debug configuration and try again.

Comment: Never noticed this. Oh my. Thanks, it solved it. Just watch my cheeks turn red now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you built project `Realm.Server.Application` and thus `cLogger.cpp` in *Release* configuration, which may reorder instructions for optimization.

Please change it into *Debug* configuration.

Comment: Am now going to stand over there.